# How do I accurately cut video and audio with ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, mp4, codec

So when I try to cut out a portion of a video I do this

```
ffmpeg -i originalClip.mp4 -ss 00:00:14 -t 00:00:21 -codec copy outputClip.mp4
```

And the video comes out with amazing quality and the sound is on point.

However, after chucking the clip into this tool called `blur` which also uses `ffmpeg` it desyncs the audio, so the audio is slightly behind, which interestingly enough, didn't happen with the trimmed clip, it's only after chucking it into the tool.

Now here is what makes it more interesting, if I were to chuck the original clip into `blur` it would be just fine.

This leaves me to believe that when cutting the clip it changes some audio keyframes or something that I can't see, but for some reason when the `blur` tool interprets the trimmed clip it sees these keyframes and does it's thing based on those?

This is just a guess and I could be completely wrong.

Does anyone know what could cause this issue? I feel like it has something to do with the way I'm cutting the clips.

Here's the blur tool that I use 
https://github.com/f0e/blur

The blur config is just the default one

```
- blur
blur: true
blur amount: 1
blur output fps: 60
blur weighting: equal

- interpolation
interpolate: true
interpolated fps: 480

- rendering
quality: 18
preview: true
detailed filenames: false

- timescale
input timescale: 1
output timescale: 1
adjust timescaled audio pitch: false

- filters
brightness: 1
saturation: 1
contrast: 1

- advanced rendering
gpu: false
gpu type (nvidia/amd/intel): nvidia
deduplicate: false
custom ffmpeg filters: 

- advanced blur
blur weighting gaussian std dev: 2
blur weighting triangle reverse: false
blur weighting bound: [0,2]

- advanced interpolation
interpolation program (svp/rife/rife-ncnn): svp
interpolation speed: default
interpolation tuning: default
interpolation algorithm: default
```

Am I cutting the clip correctly, or does it mess with the keyframes?

Answer (score 0):

You must include: `-flags values`, `-s`, `-r`, `-aspect` and `-sar` in between `codec:v` & `codec:a`.

Example:

```
ffmpeg -i originalClip.mp4 -ss 00:00:14 -t 00:00:21 -c:v copy -flags +cgop -s 640x360 -r 25 -aspect 16/9 -sar 1/1 -c:a copy outputClip.mp4
```

Use the original values of your input file.

Why? Because not all media players reads media files the same way. Those basic attributes/values are mandatory for some media players. Some encoders have different way of adding those values. By doing what I showed you the output file has higher chances being recognized by more video players.

Edit: `-flags` is optional. But the other attributes-values are a must in the video-audio container.

If blurtool cannot get those mandatory values then it will most likely use default values (which is different from the original!). That is the highly likely cause to the issue.